pycharm not able to view dataframe
I am using pycharm community version. All of a sudden, I am not able to view dataframes in variable explorer (even a small dummy dataframe).
I used to be able to click the bottom 'view as Dataframe' next to the variable name and view the dataframe. Now the dataframe cannot be loaded automatically. However, if I uncheck 'colored cells' option or uncheck 'resize automatically' option, the dataframe will be loaded and displayed correctly. After that, I can check these options without impacting the display. Could anyone teach me how to fix this? This is driving me crazy.

what version of pycharm are you using? have you updated it recently?

it was 2023.3.4. I have uninstalled it and installed 2023.3.5, but the problem still here.

There was a number of issues addressed in 2023.3.3 (scroll to Scientific View). If they persist you should probably file a bug report.

What do you mean that the dataframe cannot be loaded automatically? From the question I understand that:

You open a debugger and pause the program.
You click the Threads & Variables and then click on the "view as DataFrame".
Then a window pops up and you don't see the Dataframe there? But if you disable either "colored cells" or "resize automatically" then you see it? Did I undersatand it correctly?


Same problme here, any solution?

@NotMEE12 yes your understanding is correct.

@user no solution yet

@fly36 could you give any video of how this looks like? If you resize the window does it then display the dataframe? Also if you could, please update pycharm (as of writting 2024.1.1 version exists)

I think its a known issue but JetBrains hasn't fixed the issue yet. It doesn't have high enough priority / upvotes. If you downgrade to 2023.2.6, the issue doesn't exist there.

Since you already tried updating your pycharm version, here are a few steps you can try to troubleshoot and potentially fix the issue.
Clear Caches: Do this by going to File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and select Invalidate and Restart.
Reset PyCharm Settings: If all else fails, you can try resetting PyCharm's settings to default. You can do this by going to File > Manage IDE Settings > Restore Default Settings. Keep in mind that this will reset all your custom settings, so you may need to reconfigure your preferences afterward.
You can also file a bug report as suggested in the comment by @alex

I have tried both. Not working.

Well, I guess the new version has moved view dataframe function to professional only.
Anyway, you can still use 3rd party plugins, like Python: Styled Dataframe Viewer. Basically after you select the dataframe entry in inspection panel, press alt+shift+v, then the view will pop out

Do you have a reference to the fact that view moved to the pro version ?
